# 5V 2 Rail ORing Power Switch Issue

Tags: voltage, power, mosfet, analog, pmos

I'm trying to create a power switch that toggles between two DC power sources. I have two 5V DC sources: one from an adapter and the other from a Type C VBUS port. The adapter takes priority, meaning that when it's connected, I want the output to be sourced from the adapter rather than the Type C VBUS.

The circuit I've designed functions properly when both sources are connected or only the adapter is connected. However, it fails to operate when only the Type C VBUS is connected. It seems that when only the Type C VBUS is connected, the M1 PMOS doesn't open, causing current to flow through the body diode, resulting in an output of 4.3V. Additionally, the gate of the M1 PMOS also reads 4.3V.

It appears that I'm missing something, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. What might be causing this? What am I doing wrong? Could this be a simulation-related problem?

[image: Schematic Screen Shot]

[image: VOUT Scope Shot]

[image: M1 Gate Voltage Scope Shot]

Comment: *the M1 PMOS doesn't open* <-- the use of the word open is incorrect. You are using pneumatic/hydraulic terminology and "open" in EE circles means goes open circuit. Please use activate and deactivate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> *It appears that I'm missing something, but I can't seem to pinpoint
> the issue. What might be causing this?*

MOSFET M1 is trying to activate but, leakage current through M2 (from left to right) is lifting the voltage on the node where the power adaptor formerly was connected. This "lifting of the voltage" causes M2 to start to activate and this reinforces the leakage current into something more substantial and, within a very short space of time, M2 activates.

When this happens, M1 becomes deactivated hence, all you see is 4.3 volts (due to the bulk diode inside M1). Your question is about why it happens and, unfortunately, that's all I have time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both FETs are in backwards.  They are acting as source followers, which is incorrect for this application.  The sources connect to the input power sources, and the drains connect to the load.  Now the FETs can act as saturated switches, and it reverses the body diodes so they do not interfere in the off state.

Also, circuit operation relies on the VBUS source output resistance being very low when it is off, and able to sink enough current to pull the M1 gate down to GND.  Granted that is not much current, but it cannot happen if VBUS is disconnected.  Thus, M1 needs a turn-off resistor, similar to how R3 assures that M2 turns off completely when Q1 is off.

Also, there should be a turn-off resistor from the Q1 base to GND.  Because the Q1 collector current is so low, you can increase R1 to 10K, and add a 10K to GND.

Comment: Actually, the MOSFETs **can be fully** activated. Also, MOSFET saturation is something else and is unrelated to the triode region (which they are intended to operate in).